# Is it possible to tell AWS network load balancer that an instance is unhealthy without delay?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

The AWS Network Load Balancer incurs a 90 second delay to deregister a target, and takes at least 10 seconds to notice that target is unhealthy.

Is there some API call that would inform the load balancer that the target is unhealthy immediately?

Answer (score 0):

You could just deregister the target directly, for example via the [CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/deregister-targets.html) or [Python SDK](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html).

Comment: The problem is that it takes up to 90 seconds to deregister a target. I'm trying to avoid incurring that delay during deloyments.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to decrease the health check interval to minimum **5 seconds** in case of `HTTP` with threshold 2 so it means with `0` delay of deregistering it will not wait to elapse delay will improve a bit.

This the minimum setting for the TCP health check, you can tune this also if not, as deregistration start when the target is unhealthy so health check plays the main role.

[image]

[image]

For http

[image]
[image]

**Deregistration Delay**

> Elastic Load Balancing stops sending requests to targets that are
>   deregistering. By default, Elastic Load Balancing waits 300 seconds
>   before completing the deregistration process, which can help in-flight
>   requests to the target to complete. To change the amount of time that
>   Elastic Load Balancing waits, update the deregistration delay value.
>
> The initial state of a deregistering target is draining. After the
>   deregistration delay elapses, the deregistration process completes and
>   the state of the target is unused. If the target is part of an Auto
>   Scaling group, it can be terminated and replaced.
>
> If a deregistering target has no in-flight requests and no active
>   connections, Elastic Load Balancing immediately completes the
>   deregistration process, without waiting for the deregistration delay
>   to elapse. However, even though target deregistration is complete,
>   **the status of the target will be displayed as draining until the deregistration delay elapses**.

[load-balancer-target-groups-deregistaion-delay](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html)

**Work Around:**

One in my client project has the same requirement so I came up with a custom health check script that performs two tasks.

- check the target group health check
- If the target group seems healthy return status healthy to the LB
- If the target group status is unhealthy then deregister the target immediately

[image]